# nodejs , call method, output log flow

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs code. It calls a method, the  current code output is:

[image]

but the expected output is:

[image]

```
    app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), (req, res) => {   
    var imagelist = [];
    (req.files).forEach(function (file) {
        console.log('before resize');
        resizeImage(__basefolder, file.originalname, 0, 2).then(function(result) {
            console.log("current result:",result);
            imagelist.push([result, file.originalname]);
        });
        console.log('after resize');
    });
    res.json(imagelist);
});

//resize images. reduce image size as per divisor value.
async function resizeImage(folder, fileName, dimensions, divisor) {
    return 'resizedimage';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resizeImage()` is an async operation, which means that `forEach` will not wait until the promise is resolved in the current iteration. You can fix this by using `await` inside a `for .. of` loop (note that you should probably add a `try/catch` to handle errors):

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const imagelist = [];
  for (const file of req.files) {
    console.log('before resize');
    const result = await resizeImage(__basefolder, file.originalname, 0, 2);
    imagelist.push([result, file.originalname]);
    console.log('after resize');
  }
  res.json(imagelist);
});
```

Comment: u are also addin 'async (req, res)'